# Salesforce - Leads are not being submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, salesforce

I have a form that I am trying to have submitted so leads can go to Salesforce. For some reason the information is not going through.  This error may be because I have the submit button initially disabled.  Once the user fills in all the information the button becomes enabled; however, the information or leads are still not going into Salesforce.  The client says if I leave the submit button without the "disabled="disabled" in the HTML that the form works and the leads go to Salesforce. The problem is that if I leave the "disabled="disabled" out of the HTML the user is still able to click submit even if there is not any text in the input boxes.  If someone could help me with this issue I would really appreciate it.  I attached a fiddle, but it really doesn't show the Salesforce side of things.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/541/)

```
<form id="contact_form" class="container form-hide" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" style="background-color: #00AB8E">
              <label>First Name
                <span class="error">Please enter data.</span>
                <input id="tesFN first_name " maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"></textarea>
                <input id="sub2" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="SUBMIT"/>
              </label>

                <div>                
                    <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

                <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
                </div>
            </form>


body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  color: #333;

}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;

}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}


label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color:  #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F68D2E;;
}


#thankyou { display:none;}

#thankyou.success { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="tel"] {
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#tessellate-page textarea{
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#comments_label {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#cap {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }

   .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

  }


}

label {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}

function phoneNumber(phone)  {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: "+phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');

  }
});



function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: "+re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
  }

});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && (validateEmail($("#email").val()))
      && (phoneNumber($("#phone").val()))
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()
      && $("#comments").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#sub2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}


 $('#phone').keydown(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   var removedText = self.val().replace(/\D/, '');

   self.val(removedText);
});


$("#contact_form").submit(function(event) {
    console.log("Form success");
    ("#contact_form").
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})

$("#sub").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})


$("#sub2").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub2").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the information was not going through to Salesforce was because the form was getting detached when the user clicked submit. Adding this to my JavaScript solved the problem:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url : $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "post",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      complete : function(jXHR, textStatus)
      {
        // console.log("Form success");
        $("#contact_form").remove();
        $("#thankyou").addClass("success");

      },
      error: function(jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        // console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
});
```